# Should model validations reflect database column constraints

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have the following table:

```
class CreatePosts < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_table :posts do |t|
      t.belongs_to :site, null: false
      t.bigint :post_id, null: false
      t.string :title, null: false
      t.string :url, null: false
      t.text :body, null: false

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

And you can see, none attributes can have a value `null`. Should I reflect those constrains in the `Post` model? Is it a good practice?

Right now if I try to save a post without all attributes, ActiveRecord will raise a MySQL error, where I would like to avoid that and present a more concise error.

Answer (score 2):

Let me defer to the Giant Robots Smashing Into Other Giant Robots on this one:
https://thoughtbot.com/blog/validation-database-constraint-or-both

In this post, Derek Prior suggests that doing both is hardly necessary:

> It is not necessary to back each validation with a schema constraint, nor is it necessary for schema constraints to be reflected as model validations. There are a couple of questions worth asking as you decide which is appropriate for your use case.
>
> > 1. Are you trying to prevent bad data from being written to the database? If so, you must have a schema constraint. Unfortunately, Omakase Rails doesn’t natively support the creation and schema dumping of all common constraints supported by Postgres, so you must also weigh this in your decision making.
> > 2. Are you preventing errors that your application user can fix for themselves? If so, you should use a model validation.

I recommend reading the whole article (I have and find myself coming back to it every few months).

Comment: The more relevant part of the blog post is the next section were they talk about the difference between things users can edit and things they can't, problems with the first type of values should have validations (and database constraints) because problems with them are user errors, the second type of values don't have validations (but do have database constraints) because problems there are application bugs.